# Find best matching array in set of arrays using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm, search

I have a very unique condition to search.
I have one array

```
["A","B","C"]
```

I need to search best matching array in this set of arrays :

```
[
  ["A"],
  ["B"],
  ["C"],
  ["F"],
  ["A","D"],
  ["A","B","E"],
  ["B","C","E"],
  ["A","B"],      
  ["C","E"],
  ["A","B","D","E","C"]
]
```

Intended result for this search will be `["A","B","D","E","C"]` as this contains all items from search array.

Actually I need to return minimum number of arrays as possible and shortest and must contain all items from search array.
If I am looking for `["B","C","F"]` then its should return `["B","C","E"]` and `["F"]`. It returns `["B","C","E"]` but not `["A","B","D","E","C"]` because `["B","C","E"]` has less number of unwanted item like "E" which is not required in search.

It might require some kind of algorithm. but I tried so hard finding some logic to perform this task, but was unsuccessful. could anyone have any idea about this, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: This is similar to the set cover problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Comment: @trincot exactly, i am also confused with his requirement!!!

Comment: I suppose the algorithm must return multiple arrays that *together* cover the input completely. If it can be done with one, then that should be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

so, the way i see it, you need to loop through the array of arrays and compare each array to the original array. you can give it a score, adding one with each individual element in the arrays that match up. then, you hold on to the one with the 'highest score' and return that. so, i'll give you some quick pseudocode and leave it to you to try to work it out. if you need more help, just respond and i'll give you the full code.

```
function findArray(original, arrList){

  // first declare variables that you need
  let bestArrMatch;
  let bestArrScore = -1;

  // loop through array of arrays
  for (let i = 0; i < arrList.length; i++){
    // we're using a function called score here. we'll have to define it later
    // but for now let's assume it works by returning a score of number of similar items in the two arrays
    let newArrScore = score(original, arrList[i]);
    if (newArrScore > bestArrScore){
      bestArrMatch = arrList[i];
      bestArrScore = newArrScore;
    }
  }
  return bestArrMatch;
}

// Now, of course, we used a function called 'score' earlier. write the function
function score(a, b){
  // i'll let you figure out most efficient way to to compare two arrays
  // hint: try sorting
}
```

Let me know if this helps a little! And let me know if I can help more!

Comment: Need a condition to check length to return shortest possible

Comment: ah, fair enough. apologies i completely forgot that part

Answer (score 0):

Try using this simple approach:

```js
var keys = ["A", "B", "C"]
var input = [
    ["A"],
    ["B"],
    ["C"],
    ["F"],
    ["A", "D"],
    ["A", "B", "E"],
    ["B", "C", "E"],
    ["A", "B"],
    ["C", "E"],
    ["A", "B", "D", "E", "C"]
]

function findMinArrayHavingAllKeys(inputArr, searchKeys) {
    //initialize an empty array, here we will keep
    //override the shortest array having all keys
    var outputArray = [];
    // iterating over the outer array and taking each inner array to perform the logic
    inputArr.forEach(function(inputSubArr) {
        //if any key is not found in the inner array  !inputSubArr.includes(key) will true and break
        //the iteration, and return true, and that will be negate to false. if all keys found in the
        //input array, it will return false and we will negate to true the final result to consider

        var consider = !searchKeys.some(function(key) {
            return !inputSubArr.includes(key);
        });

        //if array is considerable and (either shorter than the result we got so far or we don't have
        //a result yet) then we are overriding the ourput result

        if (consider && (outputArray.length > inputSubArr.length || !outputArray.length)) {
            outputArray = inputSubArr;
        }

    });
    //at the end we are returning the output array, if no elements having all the keys then output will
    //be empty array, otherwise output will be the shortest first array, in case you want all the shortest
    //array of same length we can maintain aanother array of array and push inputSubArray into that array
    return outputArray;
}

console.log('output: ', findMinArrayHavingAllKeys(input, keys));
```

Comment if anything is not clear

Comment: Why would you just give the code without any explanation to it. Is this how you write code anyway, without commenting and documentation?

Comment: @vish4071 yes I completely do agree with you. was in hurry actually. I editrd and added complete explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You could first create a hash keyed by each letter that occurs in the set of arrays, so that for each letter you know in which of these arrays it occurs. This will save you some look-up time.

Then use a recursive function, that for each letter in the search array will check in which sub array it occurs, and try each of these as possible options and for each recurse for doing the same with the next letter in the search array. If any such letter is already accounted for by a previously selected array, then just take the next search character.

When all search characters have been scanned in that way, you'll have a subset of the set of arrays. Then check if the number of these sub arrays is less than what you found thus far. If so it is the best solution so far. The rest of the recursive search might still improve on the best solution.

Here is the ES6 code for doing this. It gives the output you expect for the two example searches you mentioned in the question:

```js
function getHash(choices) {
    // Return a map keyed by values (letters), providing the subarrays
    //  in which those values occur
    return choices.reduce((hash, choice) => 
        choice.reduce((hash, val) => 
            hash.set(val, (hash.get(val) || []).concat([choice]))
        , hash)
    , new Map());
}

function bestMatch(search, hash) {
    let best = [];
    (function recurse(i, set, arrays) {
        // find next search value that is not yet accounted for:
        while (set.has(search[i])) i++;
        // See if we have all the values searched for:
        if (i >= search.length) {
            // If this solution has fewer arrays, take it as best so far:
            if (!best.length || arrays.length < best.length) best = arrays;
            return;
        }
        // Try with one of the sub arrays that has this value, and recurse...
        hash.get(search[i]).forEach( arr =>
            recurse(i+1, new Set([...set, ...arr]), arrays.concat([arr]))
        );
    })(0, new Set(), []); // start with first search letter and empty results
    return best;
}

// Sample input
const choices = [
      ["A"],
      ["B"],
      ["C"],
      ["F"],
      ["A","D"],
      ["A","B","E"],
      ["B","C","E"],
      ["A","B"],      
      ["C","E"],
      ["A","B","D","E","C"]
    ],
    hash = getHash(choices),
    searches = [
        ["A","B","C"],
        ["B","C","F"]
    ];

// Report the solution for each of the search arrays:
for (const search of searches) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(search), ': ', 
                JSON.stringify(bestMatch(search, hash)));
}
```